# Joomla register new user - send data by cUrl

Tags: php, api, curl, joomla

I have this:

```
$url = "http://xxxxxxxx";

$data = array (
userId                          =>      xxx, // authentication userId
loginToken                      =>      'xxxxxx', // authentication loginToken
'customerType'                  =>      'Person',
'firstName'                     =>      'Lukasz',
'lastName'                      =>      'Testowy',
'emails[0].email'               =>      'email@exaple.com',
'phones[0].phoneNumber'         =>      '0123456789',
'documentNo'                    =>      'ABC1234567',
'address.city'                  =>      'Warsaw',
'address.postalCode'            =>      '01-001',
'address.street'                =>      'Sobieskiego',
'note'                          =>      'some info'
);

$data_string = http_build_query($data);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

When I save it as test.php and run it works very well. It sends all data to $url.

I need to connect it to Joomla 3.x. When new user registers, this script should take his data like First name, last name etc and put in "Lukas", "Testowy" etc and send it to $url. How to do it?

Comment: You'd need to build you own component to deal with this as Joomla doesn't currently have a restful interface

Comment: Maybe solution is to edit com_users registration controllers? I don't know php but I'm thinking about adding my code as a function after click "register"?

Comment: @Lukasz I'm not a 100% sure what the end goal of the cURL request is.  My answer depends on what your end goal is.  For example, are you trying to add these fields to the core user registration and profiles in Joomla?  As that is actually very easy to do if so using a user plugin.

Comment: I don't know much php so I will be talking in easy language. My goal is to: User is registering, clicking register and registering in joomla AND user's data is putting into my script and run. Nothing more (I think :) )

Comment: My script is just creating user on some web aplication and works well alone. I need to connect it to joomla registration.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here we go:

A added my code in com_users/controllers/registration.php after

```
} elseif ($return === 'useractivate')
        {
            $this->setMessage(JText::_('COM_USERS_REGISTRATION_COMPLETE_ACTIVATE'));
            $this->setRedirect(JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_users&view=registration&layout=complete', false));
```

and it works! It sends sample data by cUrl after user registers. So the question is:
How to replace test data - Lukasz, Testowy, email@example.com etc on data of user which is registering?